# How to rotate 3d objects using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to produce an effect using JavaScript/ jQuery such that a user can drag an object and rotate it. how can I do it? are there any predefined libraries, scripts, etc. any help is appreciated.
example:
thymia.world/
I'm also attaching snaps for a brief demo.

Initial View

[image]

After dragging view

[image]

Comment: Have you at least tried looking into the page's source code? They use Three.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[three.js](https://threejs.org/) is a JavaScript library for 3D animation. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/n6u6asza/) is an example of someone rotating a mesh when the user drags the mouse. The key line of code is when it creates a [Quaterion rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) from the equivalent [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) which is a very natural way to describe a rotation. By making the angle of rotation about the x-axis and y-axis proportional to the distance the mouse dragged a very natural interface is achieved.

Source code:

```
var three = THREE;

var scene = new three.Scene();
var camera = new three.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new three.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);



var geometry = new three.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
//var material = new three.MeshNormalMaterial();
/* * /
var material = new three.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00
});
/* */
/* */
three.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
var texture = three.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://i.imgur.com/CEGihbB.gif');
texture.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();

var material = new three.MeshFaceMaterial([
    new three.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x00ff00
    }),
    new three.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000
    }),
    new three.MeshBasicMaterial({
        //color: 0x0000ff,
        map: texture
    }),
    new three.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xffff00
    }),
    new three.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x00ffff
    }),
    new three.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff00ff
    })
]);
/* */

var cube = new three.Mesh(geometry, material);
cube.rotation.x = Math.PI/4;
cube.rotation.y = Math.PI/4;
scene.add(cube);


camera.position.z = 5;

/* */
var isDragging = false;
var previousMousePosition = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
$(renderer.domElement).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    isDragging = true;
})
.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    //console.log(e);
    var deltaMove = {
        x: e.offsetX-previousMousePosition.x,
        y: e.offsetY-previousMousePosition.y
    };

    if(isDragging) {

        var deltaRotationQuaternion = new three.Quaternion()
            .setFromEuler(new three.Euler(
                toRadians(deltaMove.y * 1),
                toRadians(deltaMove.x * 1),
                0,
                'XYZ'
            ));

        cube.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(deltaRotationQuaternion, cube.quaternion);
    }

    previousMousePosition = {
        x: e.offsetX,
        y: e.offsetY
    };
});
/* */

$(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    isDragging = false;
});



// shim layer with setTimeout fallback
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

var lastFrameTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
var totalGameTime = 0;
function update(dt, t) {
    //console.log(dt, t);

    //camera.position.z += 1 * dt;
    //cube.rotation.x += 1 * dt;
    //cube.rotation.y += 1 * dt;

    setTimeout(function() {
        var currTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
        var dt = currTime - (lastFrameTime || currTime);
        totalGameTime += dt;

        update(dt, totalGameTime);

        lastFrameTime = currTime;
    }, 0);
}


function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);


    requestAnimFrame(render);
}

render();
update(0, totalGameTime);


function toRadians(angle) {
    return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
}

function toDegrees(angle) {
    return angle * (180 / Math.PI);
}
```